# Django redirects to /accounts/profile

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have written some middleware that restricts access to all URLs except the exempted ones. A user can access all the URLs only if they are logged in, if not logged-in, a user can only access exempted URLs. The problem comes when the user is logged-in and then tries to access one of the exempted URLs, that is when the redirect occurs (i.e. redirected to /accounts/profile). How can I solve this problem?

My middleware

```js
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
import re

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if path == reverse('logout_success').lstrip('/'):
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated() and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        elif request.user.is_authenticated() or url_is_exempt:
            return None
        else:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Exempted URLs in the settings file.

```js
LOGIN_URL = '/user_account/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    r'^$',
    r'^tenders/',
    r'^pricing/',
    r'^articles/',
    r'^contact_us/',
    r'^user_account/logout_success/$',
    r'^user_account/subscribe/$',
    r'^user_account/auth/$',
    r'^user_account/password_reset/$',
    r'^user_account/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    r'^user_account/subscribe/(?P<billing_cycle>\d)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    r'^user_account/password_reset/done/$',
    r'^user_account/reset/done/$',
    r'^user_account/auto_complete_search/$',
)
```

I am tried to access r'^user_account/auto_complete_search/$' after the user is logged in.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found where the problem was, its in the middleware code above on the second if-statement. i.e.

```js
if request.user.is_authenticated() and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

I changed the line "return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)" to "return None" and the problem was solved.